# asp.net (masterpage)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, vs-web-site-project

i've a problem. previously, i created a aspwebsite project.and in that,created a masterpage.i want to use this masterpage with contentpage. but i didn't find contentpage in visual stdio 2008. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select a normal Web Form and tick the checkbox "Select master page". It'll tell VS.NET 2008 that you are creating a new content page.

[image: New Content Page]

Comment: Whoops, my answer worked only with a "Web Application" project! +1 to you for the correct project type :)